# Update role in user (react query)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form, react-query

I am trying to add a feature where you can update the role of the user.
the code is my hook for updating the

```
export const useUserUpdate = () => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  return useMutation({
    mutationFn: (data) => {
      return ApiManager.put(`/user/${data.id}`, data);
    },
    onSuccess: () => {
      queryClient.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: ["userData"] });
    },
  });
};
```

this is my onSubmit for for my updating user

```
  const onSubmit = (sample) => {
    // userUpdate(data);
    console.log(userUpdate(sample));
  };
```

```
 <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <FormControl fullWidth>
          <AutoComplete
            control={control}
            name={"roleId"}
            options={roleData?.data || []}
            onKeyDown={(e) => {
              if (e.key === "Enter") {
                e.preventDefault();
              }
            }}
            getOptionLabel={(option) => option?.role_name}
            isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option?.id === value?.id}
            renderInput={(params) => (
              <TextField
                name="roleId"
                {...params}
                label="Role"
                helperText={errors?.role?.message}
                error={Boolean(errors?.role)}
                sx={{ mb: 2 }}
              />
            )}
          />
        </FormControl>

        <Stack spacing={2} direction="row" justifyContent="flex-end">
          <Button type="submit" variant="outlined" color="success">
            Edit User
          </Button>
        </Stack>
      </form>
```

I am trying to update the user when i am clicking the button, it says
[image: error]

Comment: Where is the `handleSubmit` function

Comment: I used react-hook-form for handle handleSubmit
```
  const {
    handleSubmit,
    register,
    setValue,
    control,
    watch,
    reset,
    formState: { errors: errorAddRole },
  } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(createRoleSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      role_name: "",
      access_permission: [],
      id: "",
    },
  });
``

Comment: What is in your payload?

Comment: Assuming the `ApiManager.put` is using Axios under the hood, the error you're getting is related to the data/content type you're sending to the server. Double check what you're sending to the server `onSubmit` / via the network tab and compare it to what is expected by your server API.